# ReadText from file in ANSII encoding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I use Q42.Winrt library to download html file to cache.
But when i use ReadTextAsync i have exception:

No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070459)

My code very simple

```
var parsedPage = await WebDataCache.GetAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://someUrl.here")));
var parsedStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(parsedPage);
```

I open downloaded file and there is ANSII encoding. I think i need to convert it to UTF-8 but i don't know how.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to mesh with your observation that it's ANSI (how did you determine that?), but regardless, [ReadTextAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701706.aspx) has an overload that allows you to provide a Unicode encoding to match the source file.  Perhaps that will get you further?

Comment: I open downloaded file in Notepad++ and see ANSI encoding. I try overloaded ReadTextAsync and it did not help.

Comment: do you have the file/url that we can look at?

Comment: Yes. Please try to download [link](http://bash.im)

Comment: please confirm the file link, that doesn't look right

Comment: Yes, it's right link. i can download html file. WebDataCache.GetAsync() method just download html source by link and put it to local storage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the encoding of the original page is not in Unicode, it's Windows-1251, and the [ReadTextAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701487.aspx) function only handles Unicode or UTF8.  The way around this is to read the file as binary and then use [Encoding.GetEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c.aspx) to interpret the bytes with the 1251 code page and produce the string (which is always Unicode).

For example,

```
        String parsedStream;
        var parsedPage = await WebDataCache.GetAsync(new Uri(String.Format("http://bash.im")));

        var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(parsedPage);
        using (var dr = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
        {
            var bytes1251 = new Byte[buffer.Length];
            dr.ReadBytes(bytes1251);

            parsedStream = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetString(bytes1251, 0, bytes1251.Length);
        }
```

The challenge is you don't know from the stored bytes what the code page is, so it works here but may not work for other sites. Generally, UTF-8 is what you'll get from the web, but not always. The Content-Type response header of this page shows the code page, but that information isn't stored in the file.