# Error using using RenderTargetBitmap in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, rendertargetbitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap image, and have the following code:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

IBuffer pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

. . .

var pixelArray = pixels.ToArray();
```

In order to get a `ToArray()` extension, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879262/convert-an-ibuffer-to-a-byte-array-in-windows-phone-8-1-how) question.  So I added:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime; // For ToArray
```

To my code.  However, when I run, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in
>   System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified buffer index is not within the
>   buffer capacity.

When I drill into the details, it says in the Stack Trace:

> at >System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(IBuffer source, UInt32 sourceIndex, Int32 count)
>     at >System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(IBuffer source)

Is this method of extracting a pixel array still applicable to the UWP?  If it is, is there any way to get more detail from this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method of extracting a pixel array is definitely applicable to UWP. As for the error, the decompiled `ToArray()` goes like this:

```
public static byte[] ToArray(this IBuffer source)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.ToArray(source, 0U, checked ((int) source.Length));
}
```

In other words, it calls the `ToArray` overload that takes a start index and a length:

```
public static byte[] ToArray(this IBuffer source, uint sourceIndex, int count)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if (count < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
  if (sourceIndex < 0U)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sourceIndex");
  if (source.Capacity <= sourceIndex)
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("Argument_BufferIndexExceedsCapacity"));
  if ((long) (source.Capacity - sourceIndex) < (long) count)
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("Argument_InsufficientSpaceInSourceBuffer"));
  byte[] destination = new byte[count];
  WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.CopyTo(source, sourceIndex, destination, 0, count);
  return destination;
}
```

The line(s) almost certainly causing your problem:

```
  if (source.Capacity <= sourceIndex)
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("Argument_BufferIndexExceedsCapacity"));
```

...and since `sourceIndex` is necessarily 0, that would mean that `source.Capacity` is also 0.

I suggest you add some instrumentation to your code to inspect the `IBuffer`:

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await rtb.RenderAsync(element);

IBuffer pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
Debug.WriteLine($"Capacity = {pixelBuffer.Capacity}, Length={pixelBuffer.Length}");
byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
```

I think it likely that your problem occurs *before* the `ToArray` call. I'm using the exact same sequence in my own UWP app, getting debug output like so:

```
Capacity = 216720, Length=216720
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem when trying to make screenshot in UWP application.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);
```

gave me this exception when `uielement` is `Window.Current.Content`.

But when I tried

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(null);
```

the same code worked with no exception and gives me the screenshot of UWP application window.

Comment: But if you set it to null, what are you rendering?

Comment: @SeakyLone with null it renders all the visual tree of application. In my case it worked just fine for making screenshot